# Weird behaviour and OOM exception when using splitBySize in iText7 Android

Tags: android, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm using this [branch](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I7J/repos/itextcore/browse?at=refs%2Fheads%2FandroidAnnotations) of iText7 For Android as advised by `André Lemos` in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72861153/getting-specification-unknown-version-0-0-exception-for-a-simple-pdf-file).

And, to split the pdf by size I'm using the code below which I found at iText [website](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/splitting-a-pdf-file) :

```kotlin
suspend fun splitPDF(src: File, byteSize: Long) {
    yield()
    val readerPdfDocument = PdfDocument(PdfReader(src).setMemorySavingMode(true))
    val splitDocuments: List<PdfDocument> = object : PdfSplitter(readerPdfDocument) {
        var partNumber = 1
        override fun getNextPdfWriter(documentPageRange: PageRange?): PdfWriter {
            return try {
                val splitTempFile: File =
                    File.createTempFile("splitTempFile_" + partNumber++ + "_", ".pdf")
                splitTempFilesList.add(splitTempFile)
                val pdfWriter = PdfWriter(splitTempFile)
                pdfWriter.setSmartMode(true)
                pdfWriter.compressionLevel = 9
                pdfWritersList.add(pdfWriter)
                pdfWritersList.forEach { pdfWriter ->
                    pdfWriter.flush()
                }
                pdfWriter
            } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
                throw RuntimeException(e)
            }
        }
    }.splitBySize(byteSize)
    for (doc in splitDocuments) {
        doc.close()
    }
    readerPdfDocument.close()
}
```

**Case - 1:**
[The sample pdf(108 KB)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13gASVs_PigPOSNMIdCaEfhP5FsOW207z/view?usp=sharing) for which I tried splitBySize with the size provided `108000`(Bytes) which is very close to the pdf size.
It split the pdf into many single pages and not according to the size which was provided as bytes. And when I updated the size slightly more to `111000`(Bytes) I only got a single pdf which is acceptable as the size is large than the whole pdf.
But then why is the pdf only split either into multiple single pages pdfs or just the whole single pdf? Why not create a 2-2 set or 3-1 set at any point for any size?

**Case - 2:**
[The sample pdf(98 MB)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QX0NVJbZN1bOcfHp98Yp_Gpb79daT-xS/view?usp=sharing) for which I tried splitBySize with the size provided `12000000`(Bytes).
It split the pdf into 9 pdf and that is totally accurate and perfectly fine.

**Case - 3:**
[The sample pdf(232 MB)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RLHK5lDTWZXbQpmQEIZxRUpOH1X3inmK/view?usp=sharing) for which I tried splitBySize with the size provided `12000000`(Bytes).
It failed with OutOfMemoryError right after starting to split file. I think the file is large but not too large to get OutOfMemoryError.

Error:

```
 PlatformException(splitPdf_OutOfMemoryError, java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 861776 byte allocation with 359552 free bytes and 351KB until OOM, target footprint 268435456, growth limit 268435456
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3161)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
    at com.itextpdf.io.source.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:140)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfStream.copyContent(PdfStream.java:372)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter.copyObject(PdfWriter.java:298)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.processCopying(PdfObject.java:560)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary.copyContent(PdfDictionary.java:491)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter.copyObject(PdfWriter.java:298)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.processCopying(PdfObject.java:560)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary.copyContent(PdfDictionary.java:491)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter.copyObject(PdfWriter.java:298)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.processCopying(PdfObject.java:560)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary.copyContent(PdfDictionary.java:491)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter.copyObject(PdfWriter.java:298)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.processCopying(PdfObject.java:560)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.copyTo(PdfObject.java:331)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary.copyTo(PdfDictionary.java:447)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage.copyTo(PdfPage.java:401)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.copyPagesTo(PdfDocument.java:1269)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.copyPagesTo(PdfDocument.java:1366)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.copyPagesTo(PdfDocument.java:1345)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.utils.PdfSplitter.extractPageRanges(PdfSplitter.java:225)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.utils.PdfSplitter.splitBySize(PdfSplitter.java:135)
```

So, is there any way to resolve Case - 1 and Case - 3?

I also researched various questions about this for the past few days but didn't find any solution to Case - 1 and Case - 3.

So, I would be very grateful if anyone could help me get out of the problem. Thank you.

Comment: the idea of splitBySize is that the resulting PDFs won't be over the specified size. Is this also your understanding?

Comment: @AndréLemos Thank you for looking into it. What I thought is that if we provide a size then the tool would try to create pdfs with as many pages possible to fit inside them until it reaches the provided size. So after what you described, I'm now fine with how itext7 did its job with size-based splitting. But, the problem with which I'm still stuck is OutOfMemmory error on pdfs with size more than 250 MB. So, do you have any idea if there is something I'm missing in the code to avoid OutOfMemmory error? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know, but I'd look into closing/flushing the documents as you go, instead of having them linger in memory and do it only at the end of the process. can you share the repo where you have the whole project?

Comment: Oh, but I think I'm closing all the documents at the end just like the code above. Btw the whole package can be found here https://github.com/chaudharydeepanshu/pdf_manipulator and you can find the above code here https://github.com/chaudharydeepanshu/pdf_manipulator/blob/master/android/src/main/kotlin/com/deepanshuchaudhary/pdf_manipulator/PdfSplitter.kt . Also, thanks for looking into it.

Comment: I meant flushing the Writer before returning it, which should flush the underlying OutputStream.

Comment: @AndréLemos Hey, I did try your suggestion as you can see the updated code in the question but unluckily that still gave me the same OOM error. The only thing that helped was increasing the heap memory but that would still cause issues in low ram devices. Thank you.